# Create a setTimeout cancel button

Tags: jquery, html, cleartimeout

I have a text fadeIn/fadeOut script that on click displays a designated image for a number of seconds defined with setTimeout.

I want to create a Cancel button for when i don't want to see that image for the entire set time.

I tried adding a clearTimeout function to a class="cancel" and point it to a  but couldn't make it work...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/N2ELe/24/)

My html:

```
<div id="help">
<p class="helper" data-timeout-value="5000" id="1">Do you...?</p>
<p class="helper" data-timeout-value="7000" id="2">Do you still...?</p>
<p class="helper" data-timeout-value="8000" id="3">Do you really still...?</p>
</div>

<div id="image1"></div>
<div id="image2"></div>
<div id="image3"></div>
```

Script

```
var myTime;
$(".helper").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this),
       $id = $this.attr('id'),
       $timeout = $this.attr('data-timeout-value');

   $("#help").fadeOut(500);
   $("#image"+$id).fadeIn(500);

   myTime = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#image'+$id).fadeOut(500);
      $("#help").fadeIn(500);
   }, $timeout);
})

$('div.cancel').click(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTime);

});
```

Comment: Well you must of course fade the image out again if you cancel the timeout that was supposed to do that in the first place …

Comment: @cbroe the effects come second, with or without it, i tried it but it's no use to add effects now to just complicate the code handling if the clearTimeout does not take course...If it works i must fadeout the #image+$id and fadein #help.

Comment: @Alin, clearTimeout is working as expected. Do you want to continue your fade in-out motions by clicking on that?

Comment: Well how did you conclude that clearing the timeout did not work?

Comment: When I click on the text, and then I click on the "cancel," the timeout is cleared as intended and the values don't start looping again. I might be missing something, but what is the problem?

Comment: @cbroe since for my first image i had a timeout of 5000 and in that interval I clicked cancel and if the clearing worked it had to block right there with the image and not fade it out.

Comment: @alin You are attaching the timeout from the initial .helper click in the first place. You at least need to click on that once to even have a timer to clear out with the cancel button. Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe you just need to stop animation? If you clear timeout it won't work again after button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be complicating things, just use jQuery's animations and delay, and stop them when the cancel button is clicked

```
var helper = $(".helper");
var helperIndex = -1;

(function showNextHelp() {
    ++helperIndex;
    helper.eq(helperIndex % helper.length)
          .fadeIn(500)
          .delay(1000)
          .fadeOut(500, showNextHelp);
})();

helper.on('click', function(){
   $("#help").fadeOut(500);
   $("#image" + this.id).addClass('active')
                        .fadeIn(500)
                        .delay($(this).data('timeout-value'))
                        .queue(function(next) {
                            $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
                                $(this).removeClass('active');
                            });
                            $("#help").fadeIn(500);
                            next();
                        });
});

$('.cancel').click(function(){
    $('.active').stop(true, true).hide(); // use fadeOut / In for animations
    $("#help").stop(true, true).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N2ELe/29/)

Comment: Well you may be right but that was all that I knew. Thanks, it works great ^^

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code like this:

```
var id;
var myTime;
$(".helper").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    id = $this.attr('id');
    $timeout = $this.attr('data-timeout-value');
   $("#help").fadeOut(500);
   $("#image"+id).fadeIn(500);

    myTime = setTimeout(function() {
      showHelp(id);
   }, $timeout);
})

function showHelp(){
    $('#image'+id).fadeOut(500);
    $("#help").fadeIn(500);
}

$('div.cancel').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(myTime);
    showHelp();
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N2ELe/26/)**

Comment: It works great, thank you but adeneo's version suits me better so I'm marking him with the answer but the least i can do is give a vote up. Thanks once again.